# How to disable fullscreen system location notifications?

Tags: iphone, notifications, geolocation

I keep getting a disruptive full screen pop up about once a day about Google Maps using location in the background... to save my parking spot, remember restaurants, figure out when I met someone and save travel destinations seamlessly.

```
"Google" has used your location 4 times in the background over the past 3 days. Do you want to continue to allow background location use?
```

How do I stop these intrusive notifications which are a poor use of my time to deal with.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you currently cannot turn these off. It may be helpful to send [feedback to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) concerning this.

If you really want to stop them, you could go to Privacy > Location Services and disable location services on your devices. You could also go application by application on this list and change all apps that have the permission set to "Always" and change them to "While Using", but you likely have a reason to have them set to always to begin with.